# Automapper: object of joined rows to header objects with a list of detail objects

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, orm, automapper

I have a stored procedure that returns rows consisting of a join on Po header and Po Detail tables (so Po Header info is repeated in each child Po detail). My repository method maps this combined info into a Po object where each header info is repeated for every associated PO detail. Is there a best way to map these Po objects into a PO Header with a list of PO details?

Edit: I'm using Dapper for ORM

Second Edit: I added my repo method

```
 public class Po
  {
      public string HeaderField1 { get; set; }
      public string HeaderField2  { get; set; }
      public int HeaderField3  { get; set; }
      public string DetailField1 { get; set; }
      public string DetailField2  { get; set; }
      public int DetailField3  { get; set; }
  }
```

to

```
public class Po_Header
 {
    public string HeaderField1 { get; set; }
    public string HeaderField2  { get; set; }
    public int HeaderField3  { get; set; }
    List<Po_Detail> PoDetails { get; set; }
 }

public class Po_Detail
 {
    public string DetailField1 { get; set; }
    public string DetailField2  { get; set; }
    public int DetailField3  { get; set; 
 }
```

Repo Method:

```
public IEnumerable<Po> GetAllPosByCustomer(string customerId) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = (SqlConnection) _dbFactory.GetConnection())
            {
                var query = "dbo.spPo_GetAllByCustomerId";
                var list = SqlMapper.Query<Po>(connection, query, param: new { @CustomerId = customerId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                return list;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var err = e.ToString();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the grouping with LINQ and _then_ see how AM can help.

Comment: Realize that I definitely should have mentioned this in original question, but I'm using Dapper for ORM, so LINQ wouldn't really apply, correct?

Comment: LINQ to objects then.